# in my custom checkmark component i have to press twice to show that checkmark?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have component where i select a message using a custom checkmark component  and where the message selected will be proceeded ahead. the checkmark appears on the basis of the index set , But when i click once the option does get selected but the check mark won't appear rather i had to press twice to show it here is a [Video Preview](https://photos.app.goo.gl/ukqgsk9yQYhRXZhz7). and the code is below

```
import { Divider, ListItem } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react';
import './SelectMessageComponent.css';
import CheckSharpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckSharp';
const SelectMessageComponent = (props) => {
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState(props.selectedIndex);
  let item = [];
  const onSelectedNumber = (index, val) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index);
    props.sendData(val);
  };
  props.dataObj.forEach((el, i) => {
    item.push(
      <div className={'spanMessageClass '} key={i}>
        <ListItem onClick={() => onSelectedNumber(i, el.message)}>
          {el.message}
        </ListItem>
        {i === selectedIndex && (
          <CheckSharpIcon className={'checkMarkMessageIcon'} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  });
  item = item.reduce((r, a) => r.concat(a, <Divider key={r} />), []);
  return item;
};

export default SelectMessageComponent;
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted your code to codesandbox, but I couldn't replicate the issue. (https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-playground-forked-ijhj3?file=/clicklist.jsx in case you'd want to have a look).

It's difficult to tell what is the main cause of the problem but there are a number of things you could improve in this code:

- You're creating a copy of `props.selectedIndex` and you keep it in your store as `selectedIndex`. The main idea behind React is that you try to keep your state in one central location. It is highly likely that your error is caused by a synchronization issue between `props.selectedIndex` and `selectedIndex` (state).
- Try your components in isolation - you could write a neat unit test with jest.
- Unrelated, but in general I'm against offloading too much logic to javascript.

This would be perfectly fine as well:

```js
const SelectMessageComponent = (props) => {
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState(props.selectedIndex);
  let item = [];

  const onSelectedNumber = (index, val) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index);
    props.sendData(val);
  };

  return (<>
    {props.dataObj.map((el) => (
    <key={el.message}>
      <div className={'spanMessageClass '} key={i}>
        <ListItem onClick={() => onSelectedNumber(i, el.message)}>
          {el.message}
        </ListItem>
        {i === selectedIndex && (
          <CheckSharpIcon className={'checkMarkMessageIcon'} />
        )}
      </div>
      {i < props.dataObj.length - 1 && <Divider key={r} />}
    </>
    ))}
  </>);
};
```

Comment: hey, thank you for the reply, i was indeed approaching the state in a wrong way , the main problem in my code was as u can see in the video i use select inside a dialog box , the main issue was i was not passing the select component as a child rather manipulating it directly inside the dialog component which is not encouraged as state inside dialog will update if i change the import child component rather inside passing prop children component, hence it updates the whole component and i have to press twice to update . i indeed was making a state management issue as u said :) ( new to react)